# Full outer join does not work for two small tables, error 1064

Tags: mysql, join

folks.

I am currently exploring the capabilities of MySQL while doing simple exercises with diverse queries.

I was reading the following article that explains how table JOIN works:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

However, I am stuck at the FULL OUTER JOIN example (comprised of tableA and tableB):

tableA:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mysql> select * from tablea;

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Pirate    |
|  2 | Monkey    |
|  3 | Ninja     |
|  4 | Spaghetti |
+----+-----------+
```

tableB:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mysql> select * from tab

```
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Rutabanga   |
|  2 | Pirate      |
|  3 | Darth Vader |
|  4 | Ninja       |
+----+-------------+
```

I am trying the same as proposed in the website:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
```

and receive error 1064.

Does anyone have an idea what the reason could be?

Thank in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySql doesn't exists FULL OUTER JOIN keyword

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.name = B.name
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableA A
RIGHT JOIN TableB B ON A.name = B.name
```

Answer (score 8):

The simple reason is that MySQL has not implemented `FULL` outer joins, only `LEFT` and `RIGHT` ones.

You can simulate the `FULL` join with a `UNION` of a `LEFT` and a `RIGHT` outer join:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.* 
FROM 
  TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.name = TableB.name

UNION 

SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*
FROM 
  TableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.name = TableB.name ;
```

or (for improved performance) using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.* 
FROM 
  TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.name = TableB.name

UNION ALL

SELECT TableA.*, TableB.*
FROM 
  TableA RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE 
    TableA.name IS NULL ;
```

Both queries (`UNION` and `UNION ALL`) will return same results. Unless the result of the join is not unique (if it produces 2 or more identical rows). Since this question has `SELECT *`, so `SELECT a.*, b.*`, for this to happen, the tables should have duplicate rows, which is rather unlikely (a table with no primary or unique constraint.)